# Hide a Table Row inside a DIV with specific text

Tags: jquery, html-table

I would like to hide a table row with a specific text. The table is inside a DIV.

```
<div id="TBL1" class="ShipEst">
<table align="right" style="width: 100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td align="left">
 <b>Subtotal: </b>
 </td>
 <td align="center"> </td>
 <td align="right">
 <nobr>Rs 25.00</nobr>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td align="left">
 <b>Shipping: </b>
 </td>
 <td align="center"> </td>
<td align="right">
<nobr>Rs 0.00</nobr>
</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I am using the below but I don't want to loop the condition.

```
$('table tr').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.text() == 'Shipping') {
        $this.closest("tr").hide();
    }
})
```

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your question? The word `shipping` inside `<b>` tag or where?

Answer (score 1):

The `tr`s text is not equal to `Shipping` it is a part of the text of the target tr.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#TBL1 table tr').has('td:first-child:contains("Shipping")').hide()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Y8X88/)

---

But using :contains is not always safe because it matches partial texts also so try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#TBL1 table tr').filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).find('td:first-child').text()) == 'Shipping:'
    }).hide()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7WDsL/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class for row.
That class is used for all rows.
And then try this:

```
$("table").on("change",".shipping_row",function(){
   $(this).closest("tr").hide();
})
```